# How to re-create this iOS7 blur effect

Tags: effects, blur

Tried a lot but I just can't quite get it, how do I achieve a translucent tab bar like this:

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a non-destructive and reusable blurred/frosted glass effect?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/18892/how-to-create-a-non-destructive-and-reusable-blurred-frosted-glass-effect)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The bottom part is **gaussian blurred** and has a **semitransparent white** overlay.

**Step1:** Select the overlay area on the background (the original image) and apply a gaussian blur of radius 12px.

**Step2:** Create a new layer, select the same part for the overlay, fill it with white, and give this layer an opacity of 66%

Reproduced with the upper part of your reference image:
**EDIT :** *new parameters to match the original*

[image]

Comment: I'd assume this is done with code, if this is a screenshot. I guess it comes down to whether or not he/she's asking to do this in a composition or mockup, or implement it online.

Comment: @Peter Walser how to create the overlay area that will be applied the Gaussian if there are more layers? Need first to merge them?

Comment: @FredCollins: yes, either you merge them first and blur the selection, or you create a new layer with a copy of the merged selection (which would need to be recreated every time a layer is changed).

Comment: @PeterWalser thanks. Last question. To create the new transparent layer with opacity of 66% I use the rectangle tool but I feel there's a better way. Like creating a mask/clipping mask for the blurred layer or something alike. What do you suggest?

Comment: With a separate layer, you can quickly adjust the overall opacity. The opacity mask solution has the same result, here you can even adjust the opacity per pixel. And, you can of course combine both approaches (mask+layer transparency). Whichever works best for you.

Comment: How can I export ONLY this blurred+translucent layer as a PNG so that I can use it in overlays on my website? When I export this layer, the "blur" is lost. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

You did not define what program or technology you are using. So, while [Peter described a nice way to do it with Photoshop](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/20714/14041), I would like to add that this effect can also be created using CSS3.

Here's a peak into the CSS needed:

```
#iOSblur
{
    -webkit-filter: blur(12px);
    -moz-filter: blur(12px);
    -o-filter: blur(12x);
    -ms-filter: blur(12px);
    filter: blur(12px);
}

#iOSopacity
{
    opacity: 0.6;
}
```

Not saying that this is how you should do it… in fact, I personally would use Peter's procedure.