# How can I produce this irregular gradient using css?

Tags: css, gradient

I am looking for a way to reproduce this gradient using css:

[image]

Is it possible? I don't know how the png gradient has been done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're OK with using an image too, see [my answer here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/18905/8708) (you'd have to increase the blur value by quite a bit).

If you want it do be done purely with CSS (e.g. with [CSS3 gradients](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_gradients?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2FTutorials%2FUsing_CSS_gradients)), that might not be easily done depending on how exact you want to replicate that. You could create something pretty close with a lot of tweaking. You can use the method explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5341531/1832306) to apply both a radial and linear gradient style.

I put the following style together to show what you could do:

```
.gr1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #494f2f 0%, #a3772e 22%, #835019 62%, #5e3a11 100%, #5e3a11 100%), radial-gradient(ellipse at center, #494f2f 0%, #a3772e 22%, #835019 62%, #5e3a11 100%, #5e3a11 100%);
}
.gr1:after {
    content :' ';
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(238, 241, 100, 0.45) 0%, rgba(83, 89, 54, 0.01) 94%, rgba(73, 79, 47, 0.01) 100%);
}
```

On Chrome, that produces the following for me:

[image: gradient]

[Here's a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C6h8U/). It only slightly resembles the image you have posted, but I'll leave the color tweaking up to you to get the results you're after.

Comment: Yes, I think you would need multiple layers and linear and circular gradients. It will be rather fiddly, but it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another try at it (see [codepen](https://codepen.io/qntl/pen/jObbNzy)):

**HTML**

```
<div></div>
```

**CSS**

```
body, div {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
  position:absolute;
}

div {
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center bottom, #FEDB37 0%, #FDB931 8%, #9f7928 30%, #8A6E2F 40%, transparent 80%),
                radial-gradient(ellipse at center top, #FFFFFF 0%, #FFFFAC 8%, #D1B464 25%, #5d4a1f 62.5%, #5d4a1f 100%);
}
```

This produces (on Chrome):

[image: Gold color]