# How to make this same effect?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, effects, image-editing

The sharp image in the center is the input image. I want to understand how one can achieve the same effect on any photo.

**What I've tried:**

Scaling the upper and lower parts of the image and then applying different kinds of blur in Photoshop. However, this doesn't look similar at all.

**What I want from you:**

Tell me what transformations to use to achieve the same result.

[image: Edited photo]

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to create a non-destructive and reusable blurred/frosted glass effect?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/18892/how-to-create-a-non-destructive-and-reusable-blurred-frosted-glass-effect)

Comment: [Site search under tag adobe-photoshop blur effect results](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Badobe-photoshop%5D+blur+effect)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a non-destructive and reusable blurred/frosted glass effect?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/18892/how-to-create-a-non-destructive-and-reusable-blurred-frosted-glass-effect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Top and bottom section of visual seems like a part of main picture scaled like %500 or more and blurred. That's all.

Answer (score -1):

Duplicate the photo, scale it up 500% `Filter > Blur > Gaussian Blur` (play with slider until desired effect is achieved)

Answer (score -1):

Are you trying for a depth-of-field effect? That's where one part of the image (usually the mid centre) is in sharp focus while the focus blurs the further (background) or closer (foreground) you get to the camera point. For this, you need to make a good selection of the area you want to remain crisp and add that as a layer mask. To get an increasing with distance effect in the final you also need to edit this mask by replacing the masked out area with a greyscale gradient. I hope you know how as it's a bit long to describe. 
Then find 'Camera Lens' under Filters/Blur (I think that's what is called) and be sure to select the layer mask as the mask for the effect. Twiddling with the settings in this filter is easy as it has a full preview.

Or were you talking about tilt-shift?